# Узнать полный путь к файлу

Tags: c, файлы, unix

Пытаюсь написать свою реализацию ls, и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
если я открываю папку, в которой лежит исполняемый файл, все работает хороошо, но ровно до того момента, пока я не открываю любую другую папку. Имя файлов считывается хорошо, но вот права доступа, к-ство ссылок, размер и дата модификации остаются идентичными(все для флага -l). Мне подсказали, что нужно модифицировать аргумент, добавив туда остальной путь от корневой папки, но это не работает, когда задаю вручную. Что нужно сделать, чтобы адекватно отобразить?

Comment: сначала исходник, потом стулья...

Comment: В списке «разрешённых» функций отсутствуют необходимые для корректной работы программы, передайте «привет» преподавателю!

Comment: @0andriy как раз все, что нужно, тут указано. и что же по вашему мнению тут не хватает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lstat(myfile->d_name, &mystat);
```

Полный путь задать :

```
char * fullname = malloc(strlen(dir_name)+strlen(myfile->d_name)+2);
strcpy(fullname,dir_name);
strcpy(fullname+strlen(dir_name),"/");
strcpy(fullname+strlen(dir_name)+1,myfile->d_name);
lstat(fullname, &mystat);
free(fullname);
```

Comment: Если путь длиннее MAX_PATH, то это скорее всего не заработает.

Comment: @0andriy `linux/limits.h.`  :
`#define PATH_MAX        4096` . Да, вы правы.

Comment: Не понимаю, что вы хотели этим сказать. Да, почитайте ещё про `strcat()`, хотя лучше про `asprintf()`.

Comment: @0andriy Дело вкуса. Есть варианты : `memcpy` , `strcpy` , `strcat`. Мне нравиться `memcpy` , так как известны все длины строк.

Comment: Почитайте всё же про `asprintf()`.